# How to determine if the feedback is positive or negative in this circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback

Is the feedback in this circuit positive or negative? How can I know?

[image]

Comment: It's both positive and negative.

Comment: The output feeds back into both the + and - (non-inverting and inverting) inputs, so it is a combination

Comment: I would say overall negative since the lower diode feedback path has higher feedback factor and hence higher loop gain.

Comment: In general diode circuits, the diodes can either be forward biased or reversed biased. So, you have to analyze the circuit assuming the state of the diodes and then see how it behaves within each state. In this instance, there are four possibilities. You should analyze the four configurations.  Perhaps some of them can never happen, so you can ignore them. Usual nodal analysis of each configuration will let you solve for the transfer function.

Comment: Please label your circuits with component names in the future. Now I have to refer to "the upper 10 kΩ resistor" in my answer instead of being able to say "R3" or so.

Comment: Is the op amp 'ideal', or is it a real one with limited output voltage swing?

Comment: Hey sarthak, I also think that feedback is negative.  Could you please quickly mention how are you computing the feedback factors ?

Comment: @joeren1020 just look at the resistive divider ratio for the two feedbacks... For the positive feedback it is 10/(10+10)=0.5... for the negative feedback it is 7||5/(2+7||5) = 3/5 = 0.6.

Comment: @joeren1020 hi! It's been a couple of months and you've not accepted an answer, although you got three answers that were all high-effort and conclusively showed there is no single "feedback" type that can be given here.

Answer (score 4):

I simply go, and look at the circuit intensely (yes, that is a very important engineering technique) and then ask myself:

When I "magically" increase the output of the amplifier, does the positive input increase, or the negative decrease? Then, it's positive feedback.

If the positive input decreases when you increase the output, or the negative input increases, then it's negative feedback.

Clearly, your upper 10 kΩ resistor (label your darn components!) forms a positive feedback loop.

Clearly, also, there's some negative feedback through your 2 kΩ resistor and your lower diode (label your darn components!).

Which one is dominant under which input conditions (and possibly, history, because I think this circuit has "memory") isn't obvious to me, even when I look at this for longer. So, I think in this very peculiar circuit! (Where did you encounter this? It's pretty interesting, and it doesn't look like educational material – unis typically pay attention to not use K like Kelvin where k like kilo was meant.)

Anyway, simulation would probably be the way to go here, because the diode forward voltages might play a big role in practice, and things get nonlinear. I don't think you can just work with the circuit as is without specifying the diode types, too.

---

One way to approach such atypically complex circuit would be to *hypothesize* about it, and test the hypothesis. You'll have to test all hypotheses you make afterwards for being true, and all you can then say is that you found *one* configuration for which some statement (positive or negative feedback) is true. You haven't proven anything in general.

Let's do that:

- I proclaim there's a Vin at which no current flows through your 5 kΩ resistor (label your darn components!).
- If no current flows through that 5 kΩ resistor (label your darn components!), then Vin = V- of the opamp.
- I'll also assume -12V < Vo < +12V for a start. (there's nothing in the circuit specifying that. It could not be the case at the moment we switch our input voltage to the specific Vin mentioned above – and then, everything works differently. Which is why I said this circuit has memory.)
- It's therefore practical to *assume* that Vin < the voltage at the junction between your 3 kΩ resistor (label your darn components!) and your 1 kΩ (label your darn components!). So, the top diode (label your darn components!) is in reverse bias and doesn't conduct any electricity.
- The same applies to the bottom diode (you know what I'm saying in these parentheses)
- In that point, only positive feedback exists. Let's figure out what Vo is for that point, and whether our assumptions are right.
- In that point of operation the current flowing through the 3 kΩ resistor is the same as through the 1 kΩ resistor (...) and the current through the 2 kΩ the same as through the 7 kΩ resistor. The former is Itop= (12 V - Vo) / 4kΩ, the lower Ibottom=(Vo + 12 V) / 9 kΩ.
- The current Io flowing through the 10 kΩ resistors hence must be Itop-Ibottom; current can go nowhere else
- But
  \begin{align}
  V_o &= (2·10\,\text{kΩ})·I_o\\
  &= 20\,\text{kΩ} · (I_{top} - I_{bottom})\\
  &= 20\,\text{kΩ} · \left(\frac{12\,\text{V} - V_o}{4\,\text{kΩ}} - \frac{12\,\text{V} + V_o}{9\,\text{kΩ}}\right)\\
  &= 20·\left(\frac{12\,\text{V} - V_o}{4} - \frac{12\,\text{V} + V_o}{9}\right)\\
  &= \frac{240\,\text{V} - 20V_o}{4} - \frac{240\,\text{V} + 20V_o}{9}\\
  &=60\,\text{V}- 5 V_o -\frac{240}9\,\text{V} +\frac{20}9 V_o\\
  -\frac{16}9 V_o &= \frac{100}3\,\text{V}\\
   V_o &= -\frac9{16}\frac{100}3\,\text{V}\\
  &=-\frac{300}{16}\,\text{V}\\
  &=-18.75\,\text{V}
  \end{align}
  which breaks our assumption above that the lower diode is reverse biased.

So, even that "logical hypothesis"-based testing fails, too. And that's all I'm willing to say here: there's no obvious working point where it's clearly one, or the other feedback.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your detailed response, and sorry for the non-labeling of the components. It seems that this problem is a modified version of one from the book  "Electronic Design: Circuits and Systems" from C.J. Savant. With respect to the problem, I think that the feedback is negative (by turning off the input signal, breaking the loop and applying a test source at the non-inverting input). However I'm not sure. It would be cool if some could  build the circuit and see what happens.

Comment: @joeren1020 :) that's exactly what simulation is for :)

Answer (score 1):

To determine if feedback is positive "or" negative, I follow the loop and I check what the impact is of an increase on a certain point.  That can be the "-" or "+" input terminal of the OPAMP or the output of the opamp.  If you start in a good location, you end up doing the entire loop.

There are three feedback loops:

- When the diodes are not conducting one can argue that the 10k resistors provide a positive feedback loop.
- Each diode is part of a negative feedback loop when it conducts.

## First, let's consider that Vi is open.

Supposing that the diode drop is 0.7V, but it is likely closer to 0 because of the very small currents.

### The output voltage is positive

The feedback loop through the 10k resistors will **increase** the output voltage  the bottom diode is conducting and leveling the "-" terminal to halve the output voltage.

The circuit is stable when Vo/2=(Vo+12V)*7/9-12V-0.7V, resolving to Vo=12.12V, with V+=6.06V

### The output voltage is negative

The feedback loop through the 10k resistors will **decrease** the output voltage until the upper diode is conducting and leveling the "-" terminal to halve the output voltage which is negative.

The circuit is stable when Vo/2=12V-(12V-Vo)*3/4+0.7V, resolving to Vo=-14.8, with V+=-7.4V .

Basically, if we suppose that the supply voltages of the opamp are +/-12V, the opamp saturates either at the positive voltage or the negative voltage depending on the initial voltage.

## Applying a voltage to Vi

I have not computed this because it is a bit too long to do.

If the output is positive (+12V, saturating), the positive terminal is at +6V and the output will start changing only if Vi drops below 6.06V.

From there it will amplify Vi at a given gain and apply an offset.

When the output goes negative, the gain changes as well as the offset.  The input will be amplified until the input reaches about -6V at which point the output saturates.

If in the mean while the output becomes positive again, the gain and the offset change again to to the initial values.

The tripping points can be calculated as well as the gain factors.

## Summary

The circuit has an overall negative feedback as long as the input is in the range of more or less -6V to +6V.
Otherwise, the circuit is saturating (at supply voltages of +/-12V) and in positive feedback as it can not reach the stable points where the output is either 12.12V or -14.8V.

If the supply voltage of the opamp would be +/-15V, it would transit through positive feedback ranges but end up in stable negative feedback conditions.

Comment: Your reasoning seems right, but I think that feedback should be independent of the input signal.

Comment: @joeren1020 IMHO the feedback that we are interested in, is the feedback with regards to the input and output of what we want to control.  This circuit basically has 2 operating modes **due to the diodes** and this depends on whether the output is positive or negative.  In these two modes, the circuit is either stable (negative feedback) or saturating (positive feedback).  If the Opamp is powered at +/-15V it would eventually be stable again.  This circuit is particular so it does depend on the previous state.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit looks like an inverting hysteresis comparator with clamping circuits for overvoltage protection. Still, your question is foggy: feedback in an **opamp-as-inverting-hysteresis-comparator** configuration is **positive** by definition, but you failed to specify the network branch you are discussing.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think so. One of the feedback loops should "dominate". But I can't see how to determine that.

Comment: Which loop "dominates" depends on the value of input voltage. What do you mean "dominate", how the diodes are biased or else? Don't bother yourself with metaphysical questions and just simulate your circuit with a circuit simulator of your choice, if you want to understand its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Simulated with graph]
I made some assumptions as it comes to the supply of the op-amp, the type of op-amp (picked the Universal one) and came with this simulation. 
Depending on if you have rail-to-rail supply for your op-amp (+xV to -xV) or single supply (+xV to GND) you get positive and negative feedback or positive feedback respectively.